# Delayed RabbitMQ messages

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We have a RabbitMQ cluster (3 nodes, with 1 primary and 2 secondary, RabbitMQ version - 3.7.24) between 2 of our Microservices. The first service produces a message and pushes the messages to 2 different HA enabled queue. The second micro service consumes the message from both the queues. It was running good for several months until few days back.

2 days back our first service pushed around 100 messages at different time to both the queues for the whole day, out of which, around 60 were consumed immediately but the rest 40 messages were delivered/consumed only on the next day, all together at the same time from both the queues.

We dont have any delay settings and our microservices were not restarted for several months and there is no RabbitMQ connection issue as well as there were messages received throughout the day.  Its very hard to find why this happened ? Do someone have any clue how this could have happened ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If there were any connection errors or something, then the rabbit logs should give you a hint. Did you check for them already?

Comment: Yeah there are no errors or there were any updates. So this puts us in a real confused state.